# Postgresql: what order should I cluster reindex and analyze?

Tags: postgresql

If I am to run cluster reindex and analyze on a table, what is the best order to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any point analyzing before clustering, since clustering will invalidate the "correlation" statistics if it rearranges the heap. So I'd say cluster first.

Answer (score 1):

cluster reorganizes physically your data so it must be the first operation then reindex (data placement will probably changes after clustering your table) and finally analyze witch gives some informations (stat) to the query planner.